# Integration - Rectangle Rule

Tags: python, multiprocessing, numerical-methods

My goal is to develop an effective code for computing an integral by rectangle rule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLl1Y.png)

The code above is very inefficient and I don't know ways to improve its efficiency when calculating the total sum, maybe multiprocessing would be useful but I'm clueless about its implementation. Any suggestions?

The example that I'm working on is f(x)=cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x^2)))) on the interval [0,3]

Comment: You can post code as code with code formatting that is language-specific. Please do that. Then study array functions in numpy and acceleration using numba.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to use an existing function for computing integrals. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Comment: In general, the best algorithms for doing this estimate how much error each interval has, and recursively subdivide intervals which have high error. Here is the algorithm that SciPy is using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula